# redirect logs without capturing the interactive prompt

Tags: command-line, redirection, prompt

I launch a command which prints many messages (errors, warnings, etc.) before dropping me into an interactive command prompt:

```
$ verbose_tool
launching foo
(error) blabla
(warning) blablabla
...lots more of this...
(warning) blablabla
repl>
```

I would like to redirect all the "log" messages to a file, but when I just try to launch the tool like this:

```
$ verbose_tool > logfile.txt
```

...then it captures the `repl>` as well and I'm stuck.

How do I redirect the messages *before* the `repl>` prompt to a file, without capturing the repl itself?

Comment: [tee](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utee.htm) might work for you

Comment: *"How do I redirect the messages before the repl> prompt to a file, without capturing the repl itself?"* -- I would be somewhat skeptical about whether this could be done. To the best of my knowledge, stdout and stderr are pretty indiscriminate. I would  think you'd be stuck simply eliminating the last line after the initial redirection.

Comment: @Anaksunaman thanks, I was thinking the same.  Maybe I'll hack some wrapper with a timeout.